# Prevent user from seeking in HTML5 Video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I'm trying to prevent a user from seeking but can't seem to get it to work. Here's how I bind to the event. Any ideas how I can prevent it from happening?

```
         @$('#video').bind("seeking", (e) =>
            e.preventDefault()
            e.stopPropagation()
          )
```

Comment: Why not just not allow controls for seeking?

Comment: or hide controls all together and have a separate custom buttons for playing, pausing, volume, etc. Though @Brad's solution is probably simpler...and simpler is better :)

Comment: @BenjaminTrent Well, that's actually what I'm suggesting.  Is there a way to hide only some controls?  Maybe there is, but I'm not familiar with it.  I typically roll with whatever is built into JWPlayer and similar.

Comment: If I hide the controls then I can't play the video on the mobile browser as autoplay doesn't work. If there's a way to remove the seeking control that'd be great, but that's what I don't know how to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do what I did, hide the video element, keep a canvas in it's place, and keep some custom play/pause, mute/unmute button on it as overlay, and you can keep drawing the canvas using `requestAnimationFrame` or `setTimeout`

edit : a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3bsjxL7p/)

Comment: if you want, i can provide the code too( minus the css bit)

Comment: The code would be awesome if you don't mind.  I haven't done a ton of canvases before :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3bsjxL7p/, you can check it out, i have put a button for mute/unmute, you cann put something similar for play/pause.